# How do you prevent python from overcomplicating fractions if you are using variables?

Tags: python

```
from fractions import Fraction

#warning
print("Type in your coodinates like x1,y1 without a space.")
x1, y1 = (float(x) for x in input("Enter your first coordinates: ").split(","))
x2, y2 = (float(x) for x in input("Enter your second coordinates: ").split(","))
#variables for easier calculation
a=x1-x2
b=y1-y2
c=x1+x2
d=y1+y2
e=x1*y1-x1*y2

#calculations
midpoint=((c/2),(d/2))

distance=(((a**2)+(b**2))**0.5)

slope=Fraction.from_float(b/a)

part=Fraction.from_float(e/a)

intercept=Fraction.from_float(y1-float(part))

equation=(str(slope)+"x+"+str(intercept))

#print
print("Midpoint: " + str(midpoint))
print("Distance: "+ str(distance))
print("Slope: " + str(slope))
print("Equation:y="+str(equation))
print(str(slope))
```

When I enter 0,0 and 3,4, the program gives me 6004799503160661/4503599627370496 as the slope which is numerically the same but useless as I can't write it down. Is there anyway to prevent python from doing so?

I tried to use the original variables in place of a and b but it doens't work.

Comment: The short version is that you cannot, because `Fraction` does not know anything about where the value given to `.from_float` came from. The imprecision is already there in the `b/a` calculation. If you want to create a `Fraction` that represents the quotient of two integers, **that is what the constructor is for**: `Fraction(b, a)`. If you need floating-point input coordinates then you cannot accomplish anything useful by adding Fractions into the system later. Please see the linked duplicate to understand the general issue with floating-point numbers properly.

Comment: If you want to get "exact results" then you need a type that represents the input exactly (perhaps `Decimal` can help you) and you need to preserve exact values **at every step** (good luck with the square-root operation). There are symbolic computing libraries like SymPy that can help with this, but that requires doing some investigation and coming up with a new, specific question if you get stuck. (It will also be much, much slower than using floating-point numbers directly.)